# Calculating the number of vertexes in graph

Tags: graph-theory

WHat is the logic behind calculating the number of Vertexes in graph?

Imagine we have a graph $G = ( V , E )$

and we know that $|E| = 2|V| + 24$. Graph $G$ has 6 vertexes with degree 3, all others vertexes has degree of 5. How can we calculate the number of vertexes in graph G?

If I am not mistaken, I have read that $|E| = 2|V|$ is basic formula for calcualting the number of edges.

How can one solve problem like this? I have recently started learning about graph theory and this problem caught my eye.

Also , what is the practical usage of problem such as this one?

Comment: Note that e.g. $|E|=|V|-1$ for tree graphs, hence you better forget that $|E|=2|V$ thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we consider a undirected graph.

We know that the sum of all degrees equals twice the number of edges :
$$
\sum_{v\in V} d_v = 2 |E|
$$
You know that 
$$
\sum_{v\in V} d_v = 6\cdot 3 + (|V|-6)\cdot 5
$$
Therefore you have the system of equations :
$$
\begin{cases}
5V -12 = 2E \\
2V + 24 = E
\end{cases} 
$$

Comment: thanks! now i see it , but little question aside , how is this used in real world? In what practical problem could this be used or being solved?

Comment: This problem in itself doesn't have a real application (I think) however the equality $\sum degree = 2|E|$, even though very simple, turns out to be really useful to prove various things about graphs.
More generally, graph theory has plenty of application when modeling network or more abstract structure. Another classical example is the PageRank algorithm used by Google.

Answer (score 1):

Count the edge-vertex incidences in two different ways: Each edge contributes two such incidences; on the other hand, six vertices contribute $3$ incidences each, the remaining vertices contribute $5$ each. Thus
$$ 2|E| = 6\cdot 3+(|V|-6)\cdot 5$$
Together with the given $|E|=2|V|+24$, you have two linear equations in two unknowns ...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried creating such a graph? i.e. 6 nodes with 3 edges coming out of each and some other number of nodes each with 5 nodes. Hint: you can do this without having any edges between the two pieces of the graph.

How many edges do you have?

Now can you count the number of edges in the general case of 6 nodes with degree 3 and n nodes of degree 5?

Think about a single edge, how many nodes does a single edge contribute to the degree of?

It may help you to think of an edge having a head and a tail. Both the head and the tail contribute to the node they are posiitioned at's degree by 1 right?

So if you count all the degrees you count every edges head and every edges tail exactly once.

i.e. $\Sigma_{v\in V}(degree(v)) = 2*|E|$ which I think may be the formula you were reaching for in your question.